# Edit Invoice PDF after Magento upgrade from 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: magento, templates, magento-1.7

Since upgrading to Magento 1.7 the logo in the left corner of the header of the invoice has become twice its size and the address details on the right pushed back to the right so instead of being on 4 lines it's now on 12 lines.

I have reduced the size of the logo and uploaded a new one at 200x50px in System/Config/Sales/Sales/Invoice and Packing Slip Design. The logo comes out smaller but the address is still squashed to the right.

I have looked in /app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Sales/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php & Invoice.php but don't know where I would change the width of the address.

I haven't worked with 1.5 personally but apparently there you just went to System/PDF to edit the PDF templates, now we can't it find anywhere where to edit them.

Any thoughts anyone on how to edit these PDF templates, in particular the width of the address in the top right of the invoice?

Comment: Still stuck with this problem, can anyone point me in the right direction where to edit PDF templates in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late answer, but I had the same problem. I'm using 1.9.

If you open /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php (assuming you're overriding the core, not directly editing it).

Within the "insertAddress()" function, Look for the line that says:

```
foreach (Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 45, true, true) as $_value) {
```

Where it says "45", change that to a higher value. I went for 65.